# Find the max and sum of the group and insert into related rows in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a sample dataframe `sample.data` as follows:

```
x   y   z
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
1   0   2
1   0   2
1   0   2
1   0   2
1   0   2
0   1   2
```

I need to find the max and sum of x and y for each category of z (z is like 1,2,...600). I use ddply from plyr for this:

```
library(plyr)
z.group<-ddply (sample.data,.(z),summarize,max_x=max(x), max_y=max(y), sum_x=sum(x), sum_y=sum(y))

z.group 
 z   max_x  max_y  sum_x    sum_y
  1    1    0   4   0
  2    1    1   5   1
```

Now, I need to insert these `sum_x, sum_y, max_x, and max_y` as the columns of `sample.data` under the related rows. For example, `if max_x is 1 for z=1, then I insert max_x is 1 for all rows with z=1`. The expected output is

```
x   y   z   max_x  max_y    sum_x  sum_y
1   0   1   1   0   4   0
1   0   1   1   0   4   0
1   0   1   1   0   4   0
1   0   1   1   0   4   0
1   0   2   1   1   5   1
1   0   2   1   1   5   1
1   0   2   1   1   5   1
1   0   2   1   1   5   1
1   0   2   1   1   5   1
0   1   2   1   1   5   1
```

I wonder how do I get the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it directly in one step , using `transform`

```
.group<-ddply (sample.data,.(z),transform,max_x=max(x), max_y=max(y), sum_x=sum(x), sum_y=sum(y))
> z.group
   x y z max_x max_y sum_x sum_y
1  1 0 1     1     0     4     0
2  1 0 1     1     0     4     0
3  1 0 1     1     0     4     0
4  1 0 1     1     0     4     0
5  1 0 2     1     1     5     1
6  1 0 2     1     1     5     1
7  1 0 2     1     1     5     1
8  1 0 2     1     1     5     1
9  1 0 2     1     1     5     1
10 0 1 2     1     1     5     1
```

Comment: @user1493368, I mean I would use `data.table` package. Check my edited solution using `data.table`

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this with `merge`:

```
merge(sample.data, z.group, by="z")

#    z x y max_x max_y sum_x sum_y
# 1  1 1 0     1     0     4     0
# 2  1 1 0     1     0     4     0
# 3  1 1 0     1     0     4     0
# 4  1 1 0     1     0     4     0
# 5  2 1 0     1     1     5     1
# 6  2 1 0     1     1     5     1
# 7  2 1 0     1     1     5     1
# 8  2 1 0     1     1     5     1
# 9  2 1 0     1     1     5     1
# 10 2 0 1     1     1     5     1
```

A `data.table` alternative:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(sample.data, key="z")
dt[, list(x=x, y=y, max_x=max(x), max_y=max(y), sum_x=sum(x), sum_y=sum(y)), by=z]
```

Even better/shorter solution (as @agstudy suggested, should be possible):

```
dt[, `:=`(max_x=max(x), max_y=max(y), sum_x=sum(x), sum_y=sum(y)), by=z]
```

Comment: +1 fro the  data.table version.. but you need to repeat x,y? it looks ugly if we have many columns.?

Comment: @agstudy, otherwise, it drops the columns and you get the same output as `summarise`. Check it out.

Comment: of course I checked it. So my question (as a data.table beginner), is there a shortcut to keep others columns not included in the by instruction? I am sure that this exists in sql (left join +group by) so there is equivalent in data.table..

Comment: Ah now I get it. I've added the answer. The equivalent is `:=` I suppose.